# How to add another video to an android media player?

Tags: android, media-player

I have to make an android program which can play video according to a planning.  while player runs, when it comes to a specific moment i want to play another video from URL.  second video is an ads clip. after ads clip finishes, main video should continue.  Is it possible? Is there any media player on android market which I can configure or I shall develop one matching my needs? What steps should I make?